# Hera: Intel 1065G7 Stuck Low Clock Speed @ Low Temps

Tags: intel, temperature

I have a fresh install of Hera and noticed when I was running a single threaded application that the clock speed of my Intel 1065G7 processor doesn't go above 1300 MHz ever.

My temps are 55 C  Maximum after the about an hour of testing.

The OS runs my processor @ 500 - 1300 MHz normally during web browsing and and coding.

I have tried installing TLP and overriding clock speed manually and setting custom profiles but still doesn't solve the issue.

Any help would be appreciated as my productivity has been greatly impacted due to the slow speeds.

Answer (score 0):

It won't run at full speed with the power cable unplugged.
Also, update the BIOS. Check can you force the clock speed in BIOS. Check do you have in Advanced tab something called Intel SpeedStep. If yes, then enable it (if it is disabled).

Comment: Yes, my laptop is plugged in. I run a Lenovo s940-IIL and none of those settings are in my up to date BIOS.

Comment: Then I need to dig the Internet more to find the answer. I will be back if I will find a solution or any useful information.

Comment: Just checking in to see if anyone has found something on this?

Comment: I have not found anything what would help so far. It is a question for developers of Elementary OS.

Comment: Do you know how to contact them? Is there some email, form, or other website?

Comment: They have a github account resource. Just look for Elementary OS github in Google. You can report a bug there. https://github.com/elementary/os/issues Just raise a new bug there, copy your text from the first post there and provide a link to this thread on Stack Exchange. I do not know will they respond.